# Splitting User Input of Characters into ArrayList

Tags: java, string, parsing, arraylist

I am currently working on a coding project for class where we must take a comma separated list of 2-10 characters (letters only) and produce all the possible words after cross checking with a given dictionary text file.

The problem I am having is that though I can split the list and create an array, I know it would be much more useful to use an ArrayList instead and that is where I am running into the issue.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String letters = input.nextLine();
input.close();
ArrayList<Letters> Letter = new ArrayList<Letters>();
letters.split(",");
Letter.add();
```

Im not sure what I should put into the add function because I obviously don't want all the characters as one index of the ArrayList. I'm thinking maybe I should split the characters into separate string objects but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Something makes me think of parsing from my intro class but still having trouble.

Thanks in advance for any critique and help.

Comment: When you split a string you get an array. Add each element of that array to the ArrayList like `Letter.add(array[0])`.

Comment: Please include what your 'Letter' class.

Comment: @MikeKobit the Letter class has not been made yet but it is supposed to take the ArrayList and create all the possible words that can be made from the user input and cross check whether it is a valid word with a given dictionary text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use split function, your string will be converted to an array of type String.

> **Strings**, which are widely used in Java programming, are a sequence of
>   characters. In the Java programming language, **strings are objects.**

[source and read about String type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

**For example**:

```
 String[] splitString = string.split(",");
```

And for what you put in the add

you can use for loop to travarse the splited String array and put each elements inside the array list like

```
for(int i=0; i< splitString.legth; i++)
     Letter.add(splitString[i]);
```

What add means:

> **public boolean** **add(E e)** Appends the specified element to the end of
>   this list.

**Note**: as you use each content String array is a element that is used by add function.

**Note**: String is object so there is no need to convert to object.

Example:

```
        String s = "a,b,c"; <---- String is object no need to convert

        String[] sp = s.split(",");<---- Array of String is object no need to convert

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            l.add(sp[i]);
        }
       for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + l.get(i));
       }
```

output:

```
a b c
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense

Comment: @user3479375 you are welcome. happy to see you are trying to learn not just copy past the code answer :)

Comment: hope I am not bothering you but I have come across an issue trying to deal with handing incorrect inputs and because of your great description just hoping you could check it out. Please don't feel obliged to!      http://pastebin.com/rkiSk8BZ

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the Letter class does, but splitting the string and putting each letter in an List one can do something like this:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e,g,h";
List<String> list =  Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: The return value of `split` is a `String[]`. Why are you casting it to a `String[]`?

Comment: My mistake, removed the cast

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Arrays` to create a new list from the split. I'm not sure what your 'Letters' class does, but you can split with the comma delimiter like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String letters = input.nextLine();
input.close();
List<String> Letter = Arrays.asList(letters.split(","));
```

In Java 8 using streams and assuming their is a `Letters(final String s)` constructor that is accessible:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String letters = input.nextLine();
input.close();
List<Letters> letter = Arrays.stream(letters.split(",")).map(Letters::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```